# Dynamic named parameter in route values collection using Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, razor, named-parameters, routevalues

I use a helper method to create sections in my view:

```
@helper CreateFacetSection(WebViewPage page, string sectionName,
                           List<FacetValue> model)
{
     var showMore = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowMore"]);

     <section id="@sectionName">

     <h4>@sectionName</h4>

        <ul>
            @for (int i = 0; i < model.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i >= showMore)
                {
                    @:<li class="hide">
                }
                else
                {
                    @:<li>
                }

                FacetValue fv = model.ElementAt(i);

                @page.Html.ActionLinkWithQueryString(fv.Range, "Search",
                                              new { sectionName = fv.Range }, null);

                @:(@fv.Count)

                @:</li >
            }
        </ul>   

        @if(model.Count > showMore)
        {
            <a href="#" class="show-more" data-section="@sectionName">
            @Localization.ShowMore &#9660;</a>
        }   

     </section>
}
```

Now let's say I have this custom `@Html.ActionLink` helper used in the helper above:

```
 @Html.ActionLinkWithQueryString(fv.Range, "Search", new { sectionName = fv.Range });
```

Is there any way of passing a dynamic named parameter in the route value collection? In the case above I'd like to have a parameter `sectionName` dynamically named so that I'd get the correct value bound in the action method. It would vary according to the `sectionName` I'm currently passing as parameter to the helper method...

Right now I'm getting a link like this:

```
http://leniel-pc:8083/realty/search?sectionName=Volta%20Redonda
```

It should be:

```
http://leniel-pc:8083/realty/search?City=Volta%20Redonda
```

`City` or whatever I pass as parameter instead of `sectionName` because "City" is the value of the parameter `sectionName` I'm passing to the helper method.

I could do a switch for `sectionName` but I'm just wondering if there's a neater way of achieving this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't shown how the `ActionLinkWithQueryString` custom helper looks like but you could add an overload which takes a `RouteValueDictionary` instead of an anonymous object. And then it's easy:

```
var values = new RouteValueDictionary();
values["somedynamicname"] = "some dynamic value";
values["someotherdynamicname"] = "some other dynamic value";
```

and then:

```
@Html.ActionLinkWithQueryString(fv.Range, "Search", values);
```

Since you said that this is an extension method using `ActionLink` internally, there are overloads of `ActionLink` that take `RouteValueDictionary` instead of an anonymous object as route parameter.

And since `RouteValueDictionary` has a constructor that takes a `IDictionary<string, object>` it could be very easy to build it using LINQ from your model.

Comment: Great Darin... just did that and it's working as expected. God bless! :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary("");
routeValueDictionary.Add("keyName",value);
// Add any item you want!
@html.ActionLink("LinkName", "ActionName", "ControllerName",
routeValueDictionary , new{@class="form-control"})
```